# Subclassing ctypes types

Tags: python, ctypes

I was wondering whether it is possible to subclass the various types of ctypes. I tried to write a simple example but there is one (or two) things I don't understand.

```
from ctypes import *

class my_c_int(c_int):
    pass
    # def __new__(*args):
    #     print "Hello from __new__" # why is this not called?

libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.dylib")
printf = libc.printf
# printf.restype = c_int # prints "14"
printf.restype = my_c_int # prints "<my_c_int object at 0x...>"
print printf("Hello, %s\n", "World!")
```

Why doesn't `my_c_int` return the same type as the original `c_int`, namely `int`? Is it possible to make it so? If I write `print printf(...).value` it works. Is it possible to return the `.value` automatically for `my_c_int`?

PS: Btw., why is the `__new__` method not called?

---

**Edit:**

Consider another example, from the docs:

```
from ctypes import *

libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.dylib")

IntArray5 = c_int * 5
ia = IntArray5(5, 1, 7, 33, 99)
qsort = libc.qsort
qsort.restype = None

CMPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int))

def py_cmp_func(a, b):
    print "py_cmp_func", a[0], b[0]
    return a[0] - b[0]

cmp_func = CMPFUNC(py_cmp_func)

qsort(ia, len(ia), sizeof(c_int), cmp_func)
```

Ok, this works. My question is: is it possible to modify the arguments the `CMPFUNC` function receives? Is it possible to do so by using some custom/subclassed ctypes type?

For example, say I would like to pass to `py_cmp_func` the integers directly (not the pointers). I could do:

```
from ctypes import *

libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.dylib")

IntArray5 = c_int * 5
ia = IntArray5(5, 1, 7, 33, 99)
qsort = libc.qsort
qsort.restype = None

CMPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int))

def auxiliary(a, b):
    return py_cmp_func(a[0], b[0])

def py_cmp_func(a, b):
    print "py_cmp_func", a, b
    return a - b

cmp_func = CMPFUNC(auxiliary)

qsort(ia, len(ia), sizeof(c_int), cmp_func)
```

This works, too, but this is not what I after. Is it possible to have this kind of behavior without the `auxiliary` function? Kind of like:

```
from ctypes import *

libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.dylib")

IntArray5 = c_int * 5
ia = IntArray5(5, 1, 7, 33, 99)
qsort = libc.qsort
qsort.restype = None

class my_int_pointer(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_param(cls, obj): # not sure it `from_param` is the right place
                              # in any case, it will not be called, anyway...
        return cast(obj, POINTER(c_int))[0]

CMPFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, my_int_pointer, POINTER(c_int))

def py_cmp_func(a, b):
    print "py_cmp_func", a, b[0]
    return a - b[0]

cmp_func = CMPFUNC(py_cmp_func)

qsort(ia, len(ia), sizeof(c_int), cmp_func)
```

but this doesn't work.

In short, I would like to know how to customize the input and output of a ctypes function.

Comment: `__new__` in your example gets called for me (when not commented out).

Comment: @figs which Python are you running it under? I tried both CPython 2.7.5 and PyPy 2.4.0 without success.

Comment: The `getfunc` is skipped for a subclass. Calling it would just return a regular Python object, so why bother? That said, the `__new__` and `__init__` methods of the subclass aren't called either, so you don't get to customize the result. It allocates the object directly by calling the type's `tp_alloc`. Then it copies the result to the object's buffer.

Comment: If you have a callback that take 2 `int` values and returns an `int`, then use the following function prototype: `callback_t = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int, c_int)`. Since `c_int` is a simple C type, its `getfunc` will be called to create the integer argument for the Python function call. The arguments won't be be ctypes types, unlike the `qsort` example that uses pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but this code works for me using Python 2.7.6:

```
from ctypes import *
class my_c_int(c_int):
    def __new__(*args):
        print 'new!'
my_c_int()   # prints 'new!'
```

Comment: You are calling `__new__()` directly by the invocation of `my_c_int()` (the "()" part), that's why it prints...

Comment: @Ecir Hana: is `__new__` supposed to be called before you instantiate the class?

Comment: @PauloScardine I think so. It is my understanding that the first to be called is `__new__`, then `__init__`, if that's what you meant..? But maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @EcirHana: you are right about the calling order, but they are only called when you instantiate the class. You need this: `my_c_int_instance = my_c_int(1234)`

Comment: @PauloScardine could be, thanks for the info. In any case, I don't call the `__new__`, I just thought ctypes does that when I do `printf.restype = my_c_int` so I thought I could try customize the behavior there...

Comment: @EcirHana: I don't know if it is the problem, but when you override a method, don't forget to call the original method inside the body of the overriding block if needed - it will not be automatically called for you like in some other languages.

Comment: BTW, Python decorators are the idiomatic way to customize the input and output of a callable, inheritance is a bad solution for your use case.